# How can I have more than one destination for one Navigation link in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to get more than one destination for one Navigation link based on a boolean. How can I achieve this?

```
HStack {

  Spacer()

    NavigationLink(
                destination: isSignUpView == true ? SetupPassView() : ForgetView(),
                isActive: $showSetupPassView,
                label: {
                    Button(action: {enterEmailApi()}, label: {
                        NextButtonView(isAnimating: $showLoading)
                    })
                    })
}
```

I am getting this error:

`Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'SetupPassView' and 'ForgetView'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution (just to be aware):

```
    NavigationLink(
        destination: isSignUpView ? AnyView(SetupPassView()) : AnyView(ForgetView()),
        isActive: $showSetupPassView,
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HStack {
 if isSignUwView {
    NavigationLink(
            destination: SetupPassView(),
            isActive: $showSetupPassView,
            label: {
              Button(action: {enterEmailApi()}, label: {
                NextButtonView(isAnimating: $showLoading)
              })
            })
 } else {
NavigationLink(
            destination: ForgetView(),
            isActive: $showSetupPassView,
            label: {
              Button(action: {enterEmailApi()}, label: {
                NextButtonView(isAnimating: $showLoading)
              })
            })
}
```